# How to pass a custom format string to DateTimeConverter?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a list of business logic objects that is bound to a Winforms `DataGridView`, and it contains `DateTime` fields. By default they get converted into a long date and time string.

I want the fields to be converted automatically into `HH:MM` format. I've discovered that I can attach a `TypeConverterAttribute` to a field with a subclass of `TypeConverter` class, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make `DateTimeConverter` accept a custom format string. Is it possible without writing a custom `TypeConverter`?

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    // How to make this converter use a custom format string?
    [TypeConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverter))] 
    public DateTime SomeDateField { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you'd consider a TypeConverter.  Select the DGV in your form and click the Tasks glyph on the upper right, Edit Columns.  Select the column, then DefaultCellStyle on the upper right.  Click the dots.  Set Format to "HH:MM".

Comment: Yes, I know about this method. The reason is that I bind a data set automatically by setting grid's data source. Editing columns implies that I need to populate grid's columns manually.